# Install specific version of ingress-nginx using helm

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I just want to install a specific version ingress-nginx 0.22.0 using helm. But it says the cart is not found in the repository mentioned in the documentaiton https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start

Below is the command I tried and the response for it.

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx   --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx   --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace --version 0.22.0
Release "ingress-nginx" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: chart "ingress-nginx" version "0.22.0" not found in https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx repository
```

Anyone familiar with a repo that I can provide here?

Comment: "0.22.0" is the image tag you are trying to install? In case you are trying to install the chart version "0.22.0" the message is clear this version of chat doesn't exist in their helm repo. alternatively, you can check out their GitHub repo's specific tag where this version of the chart exists and install it manually from your local!

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx

Comment: If I want to install this how do I do it?  https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/nginx-0.22.0

Comment: @DiptoMondal I searched online, but could not find a resource how if I need to install the NGINX Ingress Controller using github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/nginx-0.22.0. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To install a specific version follow the below steps:

1. Clone the repo of ingress Nginx.
2. `cd` to that repo. Check out the specific tag.
3. Run `helm install ingress-nginx charts/ingress-nginx`.

It seems the version of the ingress-nginx helm chart you are trying to install, they didn't implement a chart for that version. So you have to implement a helm chart on your own in your local machine. Then you can install the chart with the command mentioned above!
For reference, you can take help from the latest branch's helm chart.

- [Here](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/) is the official documentation of the helm chart!
- Nginx-ingress latest branch's [helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx)

Comment: Tried it with checkiing out github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/nginx-0.22.0.  But it didn't work out.

Comment: As I mentioned there is no helm chart implemented for that tag! you need to implement the chart manually by taking help from the chart of their latest tag!

Comment: or maybe you can just try changing the image tag to `nginx-0.22.0` in values.yaml and install the chart!